# Controlling the spacing between markers in a plot in a figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How do I control the spaces between markers in a plot so that it although I am plotting say a 100,000 points but it shows markers at only sample points, and does not show markers when the plot drops between two points

A sample is shown in figure below: 
[image]

Comment: Hi Steve! You can add the image to your post by clicking the image icon. This would make it a lot easier for people who can help you.

Comment: Since you do not have data at those points, do you want to interpolate?

Comment: I have data at every point...but I want my plot to look like the above, where there is good spacing between some markers to distinguish figures

Comment: OK, I get it now. @Shai is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The crudest way to do so is to plot each line twice: once without the markers, but with all the points. The second time you plot only a sample of the points with no line, but only with the markers.

Comment: but this requires I choose points everytime...if you see at that sample plot, it is not the same, right?

Comment: @SteveAlex - you may select the points only once: `n = numel(x); sel = round( linspace( 1, n, 100 ) ); plot( x(sel), y(sel), '+');`

Comment: But in the example plot, the points dont look random...looks like there is a style, like plot consecutive points, and not points at drops and so on...any ideas?